# How to make modules defined in different files inherit constants from the same parent module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my "helpers" folder, I have a folder called "Integrations", where I have all my helper modules for integrations with external APIs. They are defined as follows:

```
module Integrations
  module FirstHelper
    def foo
      puts FOO
    end
  end
end
```

```
module Integrations
 FOO = "FOO".freeze
 module SecondHelper
 end
end
```

So after starting my rails app, I can use the `FOO` constant from `Integrations` in my `FirstHelper`, but is this correctly done? Is there a better way to do this? It seems very "dirty" to me, and I think there is a better, more elegant way to do this, but I can't seem to find it.
My idea is to have all the constants defined in one place, and then use them in my different helpers files that inherit from the same `Integrations` module.

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating other modules inside Integrations, you should have each one of them use the constants they need and only keep on the "global" level those shared by all of them. If you have all the constants in one place but then are using only one or two in one specific module, I think that would be unnecessary.

As of now, the correct way for them to inherit constants from a parent module is defining them in said parent

Comment: Yes, the "child" modules all share the same constants. Should i create a different file for the "parent" module and define the constants there? Or do you know if there is a more "correct" way to do it?

Comment: You could have the parent in one folder with the constants and then just create the other modules as you need them. I do not think that would be bad practice since you are creating your own "constructor" so to speak